# how can I merge 2 sorted linked lists by only using recursion

Tags: java, sorting, merge, linked-list

I am writing a program to calculate multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than 1,000,000. I have a function that correctly returns the multiples of 3 and those of 5 in 2 separate linked lists. Now I want to combine those 2 Linked Lists into a single sorted non-repeating Linked List. I tried the following code, but "next" is not a defined element in my case since I'm using the Linked List library. I can't afford to blow up the runtime to anything other than linearithmic - O(n log n).

```
private static LinkedList<Integer> mergeLists(LinkedList<Integer> ll1, LinkedList<Integer> ll2) {

    LinkedList<Integer> finalList = new LinkedList();

    if (ll1 == null)
        return ll2;
    if (ll2 == null)
        return ll1;

    if (ll1.get(0) < ll2.get(0)) {
        ll1.next = MergeLists(ll1.next, ll2);
        return ll1;
    }
    else {
        ll2.next = MergeLists(ll2.next, ll1);
        return ll2;
    }
}
```

For all who might care, this is what I ended up doing:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Multiples {

    private static LinkedList<Integer> calculate_multiples(int factor, int limit) {

        LinkedList<Integer> muls = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        boolean result_not_maxed = true;

        int counter = 1;
        while (result_not_maxed) {

            int local_result = factor*counter;
            if (local_result < limit) {

                muls.add(local_result);
                counter++;
            }
            else
                result_not_maxed = false;
        }

        return muls;
    }

    private static LinkedList<Integer> mergeLists(LinkedList<Integer> ll1, LinkedList<Integer> ll2) {

        LinkedList<Integer> finalList;
        Set<Integer> finalSet = new HashSet<>();

        finalSet.addAll(ll1);
        finalSet.addAll(ll2);

        finalList = new LinkedList<Integer>(finalSet);

        return finalList;
    }

    private static int sum(LinkedList<Integer> ll) {

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ll.size(); i++) {

            sum += ll.get(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> ll_3s = Multiples.calculate_multiples(3, 1000000);
        LinkedList<Integer> ll_5s = Multiples.calculate_multiples(5, 1000000);

        LinkedList<Integer> finalList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        finalList = Multiples.mergeLists(ll_3s, ll_5s);

        int result = sum(finalList);
        System.out.print("Sum is: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, by the non-repeating requirement, I'm a little surprised that you're not using a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and the addAll method.

Comment: A [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) makes this two `addAll` calls, but I guess this task is for learning.

Comment: It is NOT for learning as in an assignment or course work. It is something that I need to do for my own self.

Comment: I met all your requirements except for one: the answer I posted is O(n), better than linearithmic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP requests, a **recursive** algo that merges two sorted `LinkedList`s and skips duplicates.  This runs in O(n) where n is the total number of elements in both lists.

Please note that this (recursion) is not practical at all for your stated use case of all multiples of 3 and 5 under one million.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  LinkedList<Integer> list1 = Lists.newLinkedList(
      Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30));
  LinkedList<Integer> list2 = Lists.newLinkedList(
      Arrays.asList(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30));

  LinkedList<Integer> combined = combine(list1, list2);
  System.out.println(combined);
}

private static LinkedList<Integer> combine(LinkedList<Integer> list1,
    LinkedList<Integer> list2) {
  LinkedList<Integer> combined = new LinkedList<>();
  combine(list1, list2, combined);
  return combined;
}

private static void combine(LinkedList<Integer> list1,
    LinkedList<Integer> list2, LinkedList<Integer> combined) {
  if (list1.size() > 0 && list2.size() > 0) {
    if (list1.peek() == list2.peek()) {
      list1.remove();
    } else if (list1.peek() < list2.peek()) {
      combined.add(list1.remove());
    } else {
      combined.add(list2.remove());
    }
  } else if (list1.size() > 0 && list2.size() == 0) {
      combined.add(list1.remove());
  } else if (list1.size() == 0 && list2.size() > 0) {
    combined.add(list2.remove());
  } else {
    return;
  }
  combine(list1, list2, combined);
}
```

Comment: Quite complicated logic though. Can this be simplified? You are overloading a function and the recursion base cases seem endless.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Java 8 then this can be done much more efficiently using streams:

```
Set<Integer> mySet= IntStream.range(0, 1000000)
    .filter(n -> n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That's much faster than creating separate lists and then merging.

If you do want to merge two lists:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = Streams.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you don't have Java 8 then perhaps just add both lists to a `Set`. `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet` so you don't need to worry about ordering:

```
Set<Integer> final = new TreeSet<>();
if (list1 != null)
    final.addAll(list1);
if (list2 != null)
    final.addAll(list2);
return final;
```

Comment: Ok I'll add a Java 7 solution then

Comment: Like i said. This is NOT an assignment or anything else. I am using all the libraries in the world that I can.

Comment: I do however want to see how I can merge these linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 non-stream version:

```
private static LinkedList<Integer> mergeLists(LinkedList<Integer> ll1, LinkedList<Integer> ll2) {
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.addAll(ll1);
    set.addAll(ll2);
    return new LinkedList<Integer>(set);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to merge two lists for the purpose.
Insert 3 & 5 in an array. Maintain three helper variables 1.divisible_by_five 2. divisible_by_three, and 3.max
Initially, divisible_by_five = 5, divisible_by_three = 3, max = 5

```
do{
    if(divisible_by_three+3 < divisible_by_five+5){
        divisible_by_three += 3;
        max = divisible_by_three;
    }
    else if(divisible_by_three+3 > divisible_by_five+5){
        divisible_by_five += 5;
        max = divisible_by_five;
    }
    else{
        divisible_by_3 +=3;
        max = divisible_by_five = divisible_by_3;
    }
    insertIntoList(max);
}while(max<100000);
```